# Firefox claims I have granted extra permissions for sites and I cannot revoke them

Tags: firefox, permissions, browser, cookies

When I visit sites like Reddit and Twitter with `Firefox 86.0.1` on `Windows 10 2004` moving mouse over left side of address bar bring up following tooltip:

[image: Cookies 1]

Traslated to English tooltip says: `You have granted extra permissions for this site.` I have not granted any extra permissions, at least not intentionally.

Opening site info shows following information:

[image]

The text says that cross site cookies are allowed for this site. The X-mark in bottom right brings up tooltip that says `Remove this permission and ask again.` If I click it the permission disappears but comes back next time I reload the page without asking anything.

In browser settings tab `Privacy` I have blocked cross site cookies and there are not exceptions for this rule:

[image]

I have tried deleting cookies and information on sites showing this behaviour but after logging in Firefox still claims I have granted permission for cross site cookies. If I try using private browsing mode the permission is not enabled.

Disabling all addons does not make any difference.

What is causing this behaviour and how can I disable this permission for these sites?

EDIT: Firefox safe mode and refreshing Firefox make no difference. Same thing happens also when I run Firefox as admin.

Comment: If you click on the shield, perhaps you can find non-default Protections that you have granted the site. Compare a site that has it with one that doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried running Firefox in Safe  mode? Also, you might try running Firefox as Administrator to see if revoking permissions "sticks". Then, try Nirsoft's BrowserAddonsView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_addons_view.html , to see if there is a hidden extension. [Firefox installed Amazon search, though it is not listed as an extension or as a search engine!]

Comment: @harrymc I tried that: it shows that the site has tracking content that has been blocked by protection. But it says same on other like `superuser.com` where Firefox does not claim extra permissions have been granted.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Same thing happens with both Safe mode and running admin. I will try BrowserAddonsView next.